# Fit textarea width to the longest line of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I make a textarea increase its WIDTH while the user is typing. Basically I need the WIDTH of the textarea to be only to the length of the longest line.

This is what I came up with. But when the user hits ENTER still the width increases. How do I make the textarea to fit only to the size of its text?

```
$(document).on("click blur keyup", ".fT", function() {
      var newWidth = ($('#tfd').val().length)*10;
      $('#tfd').width(newWidth);
});
```

Comment: You cannot use $('#tfd').val().length because it will calculate the value of the whole text (not one line). You need to check for '\n' in your textarea value and make an array out of all text that ends with \n and determine the longest one then

Comment: @progrAmmar: thanks. like `if(keycode == '13'){` ?

Comment: Yes you can use that code it will mean you are checking for the largest line on each 'enter' key press. Even then you will have to look for the largest line on each enter key press

Answer (score 0):

As @progrAmmar mentioned, `$('#tfd').val().length` measures the total length for your text, not the width of the longest line.

In fact your `newWidth` is just an approximation and will not be correct at all if a user types non ASCII characters.

One way to approxmiate the length is to place a `pre` element somewhere, set `visibility:hidden` and `font-size` and `font-family` the same as your textarea,  and update this element with the new content whenever the user types.

By measuring this `pre` element's width you can get a good approximation for the text.

Comment: thanks. Isn't there a css rule that could be refreshed using keyup() in jQuery to adjust its width?